# How do you know if two transmissions are compatible?

Tags: ford, transmission, contour, swap, compatibility

I have a 1998 Ford Contour and the transmission recently gave up. Rather than buying a new car (or new transmission), I was thinking of buying the same car with a working transmission and swapping them out.

The closest I could find was a 1999 Ford Contour. They are a year apart, so I am not sure if the transmissions are swappable. I wanted to see if anyone here had any knowledge on the matter.

All help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Is this an American spec Contour? I don't know if the Contour name is used outside of the States, but this may be important to ensure we get you the right information. Also, is everything else about the car the same? I mean, do both cars share the same size engines? The Contour has a I4 and V6 engines available.

Comment: Or you could buy a used transmission either from the junkyard interchange network or by taking your tools down to Pick-n-Pull.  Buying a working car simply to pick it for parts seems wasteful, just drive the other car at that point and save yourself the labor/risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Mondeo_(first_generation)), the Ford Contour only ever had 2 transmissions for it's entire production run (at least in the US): a 5-speed manual and a 4-speed automatic. To make sure, look at the production sticker (usually in the driver door) for the transmission code, make sure it matches perfectly.

`MTX-75` is the code for the 5-speed manual, and you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_MTX-75_transmission) which other vehicles had that exact transmission. `CD4E` was the code for the 4-speed automatic, and you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_CD4E_transmission) which other vehicles had that exact transmission.